# How much unusable fuel is in the A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, fuel-systems

I was wondering how much unusable fuel is in each tank or maybe in total for an A320. I searched through the FCOM and could not find answers.

To add to this question is the fuel shown on the fuel SD page all usable fuel? Or is it unusable + usable fuel?

Please show the references to the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the amount of unusable fuel in the [EASA Type Certificate Data Sheet](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/TCDS_EASA%20A%20064_%20Airbus_%20A318_A319_A320_A321_Iss_14_20140714.pdf). Here is an example table for the A320-200 from that document:

[image: A320 Unusable Fuel]

In general, the cockpit displays will always show the amount of **usable fuel** only. This is mandated e.g. by EASA CS 25.1337:

> **(b)** *Fuel quantity indicator.* There must be means to indicate to the flight-crew members, the
>   quantity, in litres, (gallons), or equivalent units, of usable fuel in each tank during flight. In
>   addition –
>
> 1. Each fuel quantity indicator must be calibrated to read ‘zero’ during level flight when the
>      quantity of fuel remaining in the tank is equal to the unusable fuel supply determined
>      under CS 25.959;
> 2. Tanks with interconnected outlets and airspaces may be treated as one tank and need
>      not have separate indicators; and
> 3. Each exposed sight gauge, used as a fuel quantity indicator, must be protected against
>      damage.

<sup>([EASA Easy Access Rules for Large Aeroplanes](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Easy%20Access%20Rules%20CS%2025%20%28Initial%20issue%29.pdf))</sup>

Comment: That's an impressively small amount of unusable fuel as a fraction of the total!